# Flex tools for Mac

Tags: apache-flex, macos

I'm starting developing with Flex on my Mac but i don't find good tools to ease the development (apart from Flex Builder).

What is your favourite choice for Flex development on Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextMate + the [Flex and ActionScript 3 bundles](http://blog.simongregory.com/10/textmate-actionscript-3-and-flex-bundles/) is a great combo. Throw in [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus) and you have an almost full featured development environment. What's missing is visual design tools (which I'm sceptical of anyway), debugger (the command line version isn't very easy to work with) and a profiler.

I've long used TextMate and the additions mentioned above for all my Flex development, but lately the lack of debugger and profiler has made me use FlexBuilder too, just to get those tools.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're pretty much limited to Flex Builder or some text editor combined with the Flex SDK. I've been hoping that someone would port FlashDevelop, my favorite AS/Flex IDE over to the Mac (at least via Mono), but no dice as of yet.

If you can wait X number of years, perhaps my CocoAS IDE will be complete ;-)

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is great, but if you're looking for something free, you can hack as3 onto XCode (I've used it, and it is fine, but some of the highlighting is off, and auto-completion is weak).

As for a debugging environment, I would recommend XTrace (http://mabblog.com/xtrace.html). The library that comes with it is as3, but you can easily port it to as3 (as I did).